# TLS and Client Auth in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I'm experimenting with TLS, mutual TLS, and host verification in my app and am having some confusion with the behavior of the Integration components. I'm using a `TcpNetClientConnection` Factory and a `TcpNetServerConnectionFactory`. I don't have a solid understanding of how these components are interacting under the hood, and want to make sure my authentication is working (or not working) as expected.

```java
    @Bean
    public TcpNetClientConnectionFactory tcpClientConnectionFactory() {
        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory factory =
                new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(upstreamHost, upstreamPort);
        factory.setTcpSocketFactorySupport(tcpSslSocketFactorySupport);
        factory.setTcpSocketSupport(new DefaultTcpSocketSupport(isHostVerificationEnabled));
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    TcpNetServerConnectionFactory testTcpServerConnectionFactory() {
        TcpNetServerConnectionFactory factory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(upstreamPort);
        factory.setTcpSocketFactorySupport(tcpSslSocketFactorySupport);
        factory.setTcpSocketSupport(new DefaultTcpSocketSupport(isHostVerificationEnabled));
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultTcpNetSSLSocketFactorySupport tcpSslSocketFactorySupport() {
        TcpSSLContextSupport sslContextSupport = new DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport(keyStore, trustStore, keyStorePassword,
                trustStorePassword);
        return new DefaultTcpNetSSLSocketFactorySupport(sslContextSupport);
    }
```

It seems like the only way to create a `TcpSSLContextSupport` is to pass it both a keystore and a truststore. Why is the keystore necessary? If my server doesn't require client auth, I shouldn't have to pass a keystore to my client connection factory. The client factory should only have to have a truststore, to verify the server it's talking to.

In regard to client auth, does the server connection factory in my configuration require client auth? According to the [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#ssl-client-authentication-example), in order to enable client auth, I would need to override the `postProcessServerSocket()` method. However, I was getting SSL read exceptions until I added the client's cert to my server's truststore. Why was that necessary, since I haven't enabled client auth yet?

Finally, if the client connection factory does have a private key entry in its keystore, does it automatically utilize that key when opening a connection to the server? Or only if the server mandates client auth? It seems like my client connection factory is using its private key, even though I haven't set anything to mandate client auth yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server doesn't require clientAuth by default; there's an [example in the documentation about how to require it](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#ssl-client-authentication-example).

See [this test case](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/8c6825505030982037b51282db55afb0adc6b94d/spring-integration-ip/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/connection/SocketSupportTests.java#L412-L440).

If I comment out the code at line 437

```java
        server.setTcpSocketSupport(new DefaultTcpSocketSupport(false) {

            @Override
            public void postProcessServerSocket(ServerSocket serverSocket) {
//              ((SSLServerSocket) serverSocket).setNeedClientAuth(true);
            }

        });
```

The test fails with

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting code to raise a throwable.
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.SocketSupportTests.testNetClientAndServerSSLDifferentContexts(SocketSupportTests.java:414)
```

```java
        assertThatExceptionOfType(MessagingException.class)
            .isThrownBy(() -> testNetClientAndServerSSLDifferentContexts(true));
```

Yes, the default implementation requires a keystore but it can be one that is empty or doesn't contain a client key when client auth is not needed. We should probably relax that; feel free to open a GitHub issue to request it. And/Or you can simply provide your own implementation.

In the test case (that expects to fail) we use a keyStore that doesn't contain the client cert.

```java
        TcpSSLContextSupport clientSslContextSupport = new DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport(
                badClient ? "server.ks" : "client.ks",
                "client.truststore.ks", "secret", "secret");
```

Note that the server socket also has `setWantsClientAuth` - maybe that defaults to `true` which would explain what you observed (failure if you provide a cert on the client side). I haven't tested that; try setting it to false.

Comment: Note that the server socket also has `setWantsClientAuth` - maybe that defaults to `true` which would explain what you observed. I haven't tested that.

Comment: Can you re-post the link to the test case? That link goes back to the reference doc as well

Comment: Sorry; link fixed.